# How to run a command as root with C or C++ with no pam in linux with password authentication

Tags: c++, c, linux, authentication, pam

TL;DR How does for example su or sudo work with no PAM?

Hello,

I want to play around with suid and stuff,
I already got the SUID part and the SUID bit
and stuff, but the problem is that it's not asking me for
a password and as I want it to ask a password
and find su and sudo quite mangled in source
I am very confused.

I looked into setsuid() and getuid() documentation
and it doesn't seem like there is anything about
password authentication.

How would one achieve password authentication
with no PAM, I use sudo with no pam
and it works fine, su with pam, both work
fine, I am confused how I'd make it work

This C++ code is what I have right now:

```cpp
// a.cc //

#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uid_t user = getuid();
    if (setuid(0) == -1) {
        std::cerr << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    system(argv[1]);

    if (setuid(user) == -1) {
        std::cerr << errno << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and after compiling it with for example GCC and the file being named a.cc:

```sh
$ g++ a.cc -o a
```

and giving it execute and SUID permissions and giving the
ownership to root

```sh
$ sudo chown root:root ./a
$ sudo chmod 4555 ./a
```

it just works, but without password authentication

```sh
$ ./a id

uid=0(root) gid=1000(ari) groups=1000(ari),5(tty),10(wheel),27(video),78(kvm),250(portage)
```

(ari is my user)

Even after logging out or running `sudo -k` to
end sudo timeout it still works with no password
authentication.

- Su souce: https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/su.c
- Sudo source: https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/blob/main/src/sudo.c

Thanks for answers in advance

Comment: sudo works if the user (or group) has been explicitly granted permission.   The only password authentication needed is for your own account, not the superuser.   Since your account has been explicitly granted permission, there is no need for authentication of the password of the superuser.   The sudo executable runs as root  (i.e. setuid) so, once it confirms you have been granted permission, does not need to provide the root password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the basics: each process has a userid and a groupid (I am going to ignore supplemental attributes like additional groupids).

Userid 0 is root. That's it, end of story.

When you have a process whose userid is 0, it's a root process. End of story.

How a process acquires its userid 0 is immaterial. If a process's userid is 0, it is a root process, and that's it.

When you go through the motions of setting up a setuid process, that `setuid(0)`s itself, you're done. You're a root process. That's it. There's nothing more to say about it.

> setsuid() and getuid() documentation and it doesn't seem like there is
> anything about password authentication.

Correct. All they do is adjust/update the userid. That's it. There's nothing more to it.

The `su` and `sudo` processes do the following:

1. They are setuid executables.

```
$ ls -al /bin/su /bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root  57504 Aug 17 04:59 /bin/su
---s--x--x. 1 root root 185440 Aug  7 13:17 /bin/sudo
```

Does this look familiar to you? Your hand-made setuid program's permissions looks identical to this, doesn't it?

2. But before they go any further, they demand that you provide an acceptable password (or meet some other criteria, in some form or fashion, it is immaterial what the exact details of acceptable authentication criteria is, a password in `su`'s case, or an acceptable match in `sudo`'s configuration). If you don't they terminate with no further action taking place.

All the password validation logic, involving PAM or some other authentication framework, is implemented by the `su` and `sudo` processes themselves. Unless you provide acceptable authentication credentials (whatever it means for `su` or `sudo`) they terminate with no further action taking place. A successful authentication results in a shell, or an executed command, but that's for the very simple, elementary reason that the `su` and `sudo` programs themselves used setuid (the permission bit and the system call) to acquire root privileges, as the first order of business.